# Change MySQL ODBC Driver to .net Provider

Tags: mysql, vb.net, odbc, connector

Having to support an older VB.Net application, I get performance issues when several workstations are working with the MySQL database via ODBC at the same time. I'm now thinking about switching from ODBC to the MySQL Connector/NET.

I don't know Connector/NET at all. Does anybody have experiences with a switch like this? Are there any caveats? Is it even worthwile? Would it be a lot of work (the app relies heavily on MySQL)? I didn't find anything about the efford needed. Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: There's very little to it. ADO.NET is designed that the code uses the same pattern regardless of the provider. Once you've referenced `MySql.Data.dll` you can simply make a like for like replaced, e.g. `MySqlConnection` for `OdbcConnection`, etc. You'll need to make sure that you use an appropriate connection string, which you can find [here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/). Other than that, most things should simply work as they are. If you encounter specific issues along the way, ask here about them at the time, which is what this site is actually for.

Comment: Thank you, jmcilhinney! Sounds really great. I'll try it.

Comment: Tried it, and it really was easy. Thanks again!